# Portrait to landscape the width exceeds in Mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm developing a responsive site, but I can see well only in portrait when turning to landscape all elements beyond

[screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLmAl.jpg)

My media query to mobile is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {

 .. content mobile

}
```

Comment: Are you using the viewport meta tags?

Comment: Yes,
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: Have you set `max-width: 100%` on your html and body elements, as well as `overflow-x: hidden;`?

Comment: i put now but still remains the same

Comment: ok. It's hard to say without seeing the code, can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:640px)
```

A window with a max-width of 640px that you want to apply these styles.

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px)
```

A device with a screen and a window with max-width of 640px apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying screen, the most common other one being print.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px)
```

The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such media type as "only", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

Hopefully this helps on media queries.